# C++11 Using "Range-based for loop" (for each) for dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, foreach, std

If I have a static array, I can do something like that:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
for (const auto x: a) {printf("%d\n", x);}
```

Can I do something similar when I have a pointer (int* b) and array size (N)?

I'd rather avoid defining my own begin() and end() functions.

I'd also prefer not using std::for_each, but it's an option.

Comment: ...a "old" normal for-loop?

Comment: Instead of a pointer and size as separate items, why not a `std::vector`?

Comment: No, because of a quirky detail about namespaces, and even if possible the loop wouldn't know the size of the dynamic array. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242073/viewing-a-raw-pointer-as-a-range-in-range-based-for-loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a container-like wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    T* ptr;
    std::size_t length;
};

template <typename T>
Wrapper<T> make_wrapper(T* ptr, std::size_t len) {return {ptr, len};}

template <typename T>
T* begin(Wrapper<T> w) {return w.ptr;}

template <typename T>
T* end(Wrapper<T> w) {return begin(w) + w.length;}
```

Usage:

```
for (auto i : make_wrapper(a, sizeof a / sizeof *a))
    std::cout << i << ", ";**
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/468af3089677261a).

With C++1Z we will hopefully be able to use `std::array_view` instead.

Comment: How will the array_view be used?